# Calculus of variations when target space has boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, vector-bundles, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M,N$ be smooth oriented Riemannian manifolds; $M$ closed and $N$ with non-empty boundary. Let $f:M \to N$ be smooth and suppose the image of $f$ intersects $\partial N$.

Let $$W:=\{V \in \Gamma(f^*TN)\, | \, \text{There exist a variation  }\,  f_t \text{  with variation field } V \}.$$

(By a variation we mean a smooth family $f_t$, such that $f_0=f,\frac{\partial f_t}{\partial t}|_{t=0}=V$).

> **Question:**
>
> Let $A \in \Gamma(f^*TN)$ and suppose $\langle A,V \rangle=0$ for every $V \in W$. Is it true that $A=0$?

(The inner product $\langle A,V \rangle$ is the integral product of sections of $f^*TN$ induced by the metrics on $M,N$).

The point is that $W$ is constrained, it is a strict subset of $\Gamma(f^*TN)$: For every $p \in M$, such that $f(p) \in \partial N$, $V(p)$ must be tangent to $\partial N$ or "inward-pointing" (it cannot point outside). This is clearly a necessary condition for a variation to exist.

> A subquestion: Is this condition sufficient for the existence of a variation?

Since $W \subsetneq \Gamma(f^*TN)$ we cannot use directly the density of the smooth sections to conclude $A=0$.

---

Of course, the motivation is calculus of variations. If there is some reference which treats this issue I would be happy to know.

Comment: Intuitively this seems true, since whenever a vector is not admissible, its negative is. More detail: we can show $A = 0$ near $p$ by testing against a local basis of variation fields supported in a small neighbourhood of $p$. Since we can always choose every element of the basis to be inwards-pointing (since locally we're just working with a half-space), the argument should go through.

Comment: Regarding the subquestion, this should be reasonably easy to prove thanks to the compactness of the domain - just show that $p \mapsto \exp_{f(p)} (t V(p))$ stays inside $N$ for small $t$.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I thought. Your support encourages me to fill in all the details.

Comment: The book "Two-dimensional geometric variational problems" by Jost may be helpful.